# Generate UML diagram from C# class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, uml

I have nHibernate-generated classes functioning as the BO for an MVC project persisting to a SQL db. I'd like to render the existing code into UML diagrams so I can start playing around with code gen utilities.

Similar to what's asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556731/is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-uml-class-diagram-from-an-existing-mysql-database) only for SQL/nhibernate - SO suggests [Tools for generating UML class diagram from C# source or dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556731/is-there-a-way-to-generate-a-uml-class-diagram-from-an-existing-mysql-database) and that's really very close - except the last answer there is all of 2 years old. Surely the body of knowledge has expanded since.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No tool is required:

- Right-click your project name, then select *View Class Diagram*, which will automatically generate a list of all your classes.
- After that, I'd delete any classes that you don't care about, and expand the ones you do care about.

**I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio 2010**.

[image: Where to select view class diagram]