# UML class diagram from ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, uml

Can I  generate an UML class diagram from my Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET MVC Project?
What about the relationships by arrows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just so happens that Visual Studio (2010,2012,and 2013) supports this kind of functionality. In fact [MSDN has a blurb on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Actually, there's been a [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775454/generate-uml-diagram-from-c-sharp-class) asked on the very topic as well